# Ubuntu Studio, is this just Ubuntu with graphically oriented apps preinstalled?

Tags: ubuntu-studio

Or is it more than this?
Like, are its iner workings better suitable to work with graphics?

Also, when Ubuntu 16.04 becomes officially stable, will it be understood Ubuntu Studio will turn 16.04 too?

Thanks,

DPC

Comment: Yes, it helps. Thanks cfhowlett :)
Got more info on this thanks to the people at ubuntuforums.org too:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2318464&p=13461089#post13461089

Comment: I believe it includes a low latency kernel, that would be about it I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Studio is a multimedia OS with creative tools for audio, video, photographic and graphic production.

Technically, as they are in the Ubuntu software repositories, you could install the default Ubuntu Studio apps in any of the official Ubuntu flavors.

Ubuntu Studio is built on top of Xubuntu so is less demanding on system resources compared to Ubuntu with Unity desktop environment.

Ubuntu Studio will not "turn" LTS.  16.04, like 14.04 will be released as an LTS.

Hope this helps.  See [the Ubuntu Studio support page](http://ubuntustudio.org/support) for more information.